# Open and communicate with Excel in my Qt Application

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qt5, activeqt

I'm actually creating an application in QtCreator (open source), and I need to open Excel and communicate by sending to Excel data to show. I try to `#include <QAxWidget>` , and to modify my `.pro` file with:

```
CONFIG+= axcontainer
Qt += activeqt
```

But it didn't work. I've got the error `QAxWidget was not declared in this scope`. I read lots of things contradictory on the Internet, like you must paid licence or else.

Can you explain to me, if there's a way to solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: "But it didn't work" ? Please be much specific - what does not work? Errors, logs etc. are appreciated.

Comment: @Final Contest : Yep I edit it, but the error is not revelant, because this is just a try, and I don't really know how to do, I just add library and pray, but if someone can give me a good method or explanation. I'm on QT5 Windows 7.

Comment: What is your QT version 4\ 5?

Comment: you have to include like `#include <ActiveQt/QAxWidget>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "Qt5-way" of using the module from your project file:

```
QT += axcontainer
```

Also, you need to include the necessary header of course:

```
#include <QAxWidget>
```

You can find the more thorough explanation [here with examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/activeqt-index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I can now call excel but still not show a window excel, really strange. I'm going to read the doc.